# Не точный вызов BroadcastReciever'a из AlarmManager'a

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Я создаю `AlarmManager` и настраиваю вызов каждые 15 минут. Точкой вызова я назначаю половину текущего часа (в данном случае, 13:30), однако `AlarmManager` сначала опаздывает на минуту, а потом еще раз опаздывает на минуту! Потом я получаю еще более странный результат: мой `BroadcastReciever` вызывается на 2 минуты раньше и срабатывает точно в час, потом все идет нормально, каждые 15 минут. Вот лог:

```
11-01 13:31:07.940 26601-26601/? I/RLOG: onReceive
11-01 13:47:44.703 26601-26601/? I/RLOG: onReceive
11-01 14:00:47.623 26601-26601/? I/RLOG: onReceive
11-01 14:15:00.601 26601-26601/? I/RLOG: onReceive
11-01 14:30:00.587 26601-26601/? I/RLOG: onReceive
```

Вот мой код вызова:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationShower.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationShower.EXTRA_NOTIFICATIONS_ARRAY, notifications);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            nextHourInMs() - 30 * 60 * 1000,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
            pendingIntent);
```

---

Почему `AlarmManager` срабатывает позже назначенного времени несколько раз подряд, а потом "наверстывает" упущенное время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В официальной документации написано, что alarmmanger не гарантирует выполнения в точное время